# Timer is skipping its first second each time its fired?

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I run a timer at a user defined time. If i set this to 1 minute, and fire it, the timer will skip the 59th second and start at 58 after a bit of delay. When i leave the view and come back it reconstructs the timer with the elapsed difference removed, but again takes a second off this so it can make the timer quite inaccurate!

Any idea why this may be happening? Below is the core of my timers code, I can provide any wider code needed if this isnt sufficient:

```
func createTimer(stopDate: Date) {
    print("CONSTRUCTING A TIMER")
    userDefaults.set(stopDate, forKey: "setStopDate")
    restTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(RestController.updateRestTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateRestTimer() {
    let presentTime = Date()
    let stoppedTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "setStopDate") as? Date

    if stoppedTime?.compare(presentTime) == .orderedDescending {
        restRemainingCountdownLabel.text = dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: presentTime, to: stoppedTime!) // this is where that first second is missed
        print(stoppedTime as Any)
    } else {
        self.stopTimer()
        userDefaults.set(nil, forKey: "ViewDidChangeTime")
        self.restRemainingCountdownLabel.text = "Done"
    }
}

let dateComponentsFormatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
    let _formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    _formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
    _formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
    _formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
    return _formatter
}()
```

Comment: Timers are not about "accuracy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you decide when the stop time is. Then, a small amount of time later, you schedule a timer to fire in 1 second (which will be slightly less than 59 seconds from your stop time).

At some point slightly after one second passes (timers are not perfect, but they're never early), your timer fires, and slightly after that you fetch the current time. At this point it is *definitely* less than 59 seconds until your stop time (all the little errors are in one direction, forward, so they compound). Even if the errors balanced, they probably wouldn't balance perfectly.

OK, so it's somewhere between 58 and 59 seconds until your stop time. Well, almost certainly more than 58 seconds, and guaranteed less than 59 seconds. Then you hand it to the date components formatter with minutes and seconds allowed.

The date components formatter does not round. "More than 58 and less than 59" is 58. So it prints 58.

What you probably want is rounding, but the formatter truncates. That's no problem; it's easy to turn truncation into rounding: just add half before truncating. Because you're counting down, you want to subtract 0.5 from the current time (because two negatives make a positive; or you could compute the difference and then add 0.5, but this is easier):

```
let presentTime = Date().addingTimeInterval(-0.5)
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks for the concise and accurate answer, the suggested fix resolved the issue!